# Возможно ли создать или отследить событие на изменение Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Возможно ли каким то образом(через api `vue.js`, `nuxt.js` или `javascript`)
Отследить событие на изменение данных в локальном хранилище?
Если да - то каким образом это сделать проще всего?
(какие вообще есть варианты реализации данной задачи?)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

Comment: только на другой вкладке

Comment: не совсем понял про другую вкладку - что имеете ввиду конкретно?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/653850/186999

Comment: А что написать декоратор на storage нельзя и заменить api чтоб следить столько сколько хотите.

Comment: пока что не знаком с подобным решением - можите скинуть какой то пример?